# How to specify timestamp in avro schema

Tags: java, hive, avro

I am trying to convert this value `1520200800049` in `Avro`. This is the specification of the field in my schema which is a `union` schema by the way:

```
{
 "name" : "TimestampField"
 "type" : ["null",{
    "type":"long",
    "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
 }]
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]: 1520200800049 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:740) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:166) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) 
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62) 
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:302)
```

When I change the schema to:

```
{
 "name" : "TimestampField"
 "type" : ["null" , "long"]
}
```

It works. But this is not the point. I want to convert it to `timestamp` for `Hive` purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported from Hive 1.1. Details [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8131?attachmentOrder=desc)

Comment: Thank you for the information. But do you have an idea why the schema with the logical type is not working? I believe this is how it should be done. However, I don't see where the bug is

Comment: can you share your Hive version?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Avro JAR in your Hive Server's classpath. It's probably the 1.7 one which does NOT support logical types (https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/spec.html)